Snackbar component throws error when using children prop
so i made a snackbar.
In my case, I use the snackbar for notification that successfully added data, instead of the snackbar appearing, I get 3 kind of error

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'ForwardRef(Alert)', expected a ReactNode
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
console.js:288 The above error occurred in the <div> component:

Anyone know how to fix this error, this is my first time got this kind of error, and also here's my snackbar code
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, forwardRef } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@mui/material/Alert";

const Alert = forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

const SnackbarContext = createContext();

export const useSnackbar = () => {
  return useContext(SnackbarContext);
};

const SnackbarProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [snackbar, setSnackbar] = useState({
    open: false,
    message: "",
    severity: "info",
  });

  const showSnackbar = (message = "", severity = "info") => {
    setSnackbar({ open: true, message: message || "No message", severity });
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }
    setSnackbar({ ...snackbar, open: false });
  };

  return (
    <SnackbarContext.Provider value={showSnackbar}>
      {children}
      {snackbar.open && snackbar.message && (
        <Snackbar
          open={snackbar.open}
          autoHideDuration={6000}
          onClose={handleClose}
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
        >
          <Alert
            onClose={handleClose}
            severity={snackbar.severity}
            sx={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            {snackbar.message}
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
      )}
    </SnackbarContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SnackbarProvider;


I tried to make default message but it doesn't do anything, does the backend also affect? because previously this problem did not occur, or the cause is where my snackbar is used?

Welcome to SO! Seems like you pass invalid children. How do you use your SnackbarProvider component? Can you share that code as well? Make sure to provide a [mcve].

Hey, thanks for the respond. I post an answer of the code example where's the problem come, I hope you see it. Thank you!

I would like to ask permission to tag you in this post. Thank you so much for understanding!
Sure, here's the main problem
`
api
  .post(${API_URL}/users, body)
  .then((response) => {
    showSnackbar(Account succesfully rugister, success);
    setAkunBaru({
      email: response.data.email,
      full_name: response.data.full_name,
      password: response.data.password,
    });
  })

`
I don't know why that part causes an error, even though the way to use the snackbar in other files is the same as using showSnackbar() Is it because i put it inside then?

My guess is that you are passing an object instead of a string to your showSnackbar method. so the snackbar.message became an object and thus not a valid child

Thanks for the answer, I will give it a try

@Rafirizqullahramadhan quotation marks missing in the code you pasted where you call showSnackbar, do you have quotation marks in your actual code?

yes i got quotation marks in my actual code @ryonion
